# Filename from Frame Notification Bar

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

Does anyone know if there is a method to pull the filename from the "Frame Notification Bar" in IE11 using hwnd?  The code below works great but I am trying to find a better method of finding the file (its dynamically named) then pulling the most recent file from the download folder.  Thanks in advance!

```
Sub SaveFile(IE As InternetExplorerMedium)
Dim o As IUIAutomation, buffer As String, length As Long, result As Long, e      As IUIAutomationElement, h As Long
Set o = New CUIAutomation
h = IE.hWnd
h = FindWindowEx(h, 0, "Frame Notification Bar", vbNullString)
If h = 0 Then Exit Sub
Set e = o.ElementFromHandle(ByVal h)
Dim iCnd As IUIAutomationCondition
Set iCnd = o.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Save")
Dim Button As IUIAutomationElement
Set Button = e.FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, iCnd)
Dim InvokePattern As IUIAutomationInvokePattern
Set InvokePattern = Button.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)
InvokePattern.Invoke
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a old question but since there is no answer and that I found a way to get it, I think it's good to share it.

The element you are looking for is `Notification bar Text`

I based my solution on this tutorial :

https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/using-uiautomationclient-to-automate-the-save-as-file-download-in-ie11.1086615/

Add those declarations :

```
        Dim iCnd2 As IUIAutomationCondition
        Dim iCnd3 As IUIAutomationCondition
        Dim iCnd2and3 As IUIAutomationCondition
        Dim NotificationBarText As IUIAutomationElement
```

And after `Set e = o.ElementFromHandle(ByVal h)` add this :

```
        Set iCnd2 = o.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Notification bar Text")
        Set iCnd3 = o.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_ControlTypePropertyId, UIA_TextControlTypeId)
        Set iCnd2and3 = o.CreateAndCondition(iCnd2, iCnd3)
        Set NotificationBarText = e.FindFirst(TreeScope_Descendants, iCnd2and3)
        NotificationBarTextString = NotificationBarText.GetCurrentPropertyValue(UIA_ValueValuePropertyId)
        baseUrl = Mid(Mid(IE.LocationURL, InStr(IE.LocationURL, "//") + 2), 1, InStr(Mid(IE.LocationURL, InStr(IE.LocationURL, "//") + 2), "/") - 1)
        FileName = Replace(Replace(NotificationBarTextString, "Do you want to open or save ", ""), " from " & baseUrl & "?", "")
```